# How to setup public API call for my local setup?

Tags: javascript, cors, axios

I am working on a local project for myself where I need to make a call to public API of bitrex.com. Inititally, I thought I will call to their api from axios.get('url'). However, I did not think that will be a problem since I made a successful request using postman.
I encountered CORS problem if I simply call that url. I had a similar problem a while before but the server was mine and I set it to accept all API call. 
What are my possible options here?

Comment: Share some code snippet of what have you done so far and where exactly you faced an issue..

Answer (score 0):

You can always start your browser [unsafely, by disabling web security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177718/4875631) while testing, which ignores COR's headers.

> chromium-browser --disable-web-security --user-data-dir

**Note of caution**: Do not use this outside of development! Stick requests to localhost as you're opening up your browser to a whole mess of security concerns if you use it to navigate to other sites.